# Entity Framework exclude related table with where

Tags: linq, entity, entity-framework-5

i have 4 entities which are Retailer, Store, Group, User

Each retailer can have many Stores and many Users, Users can only be part of one group and there are many Stores in a group, one store can also be in many groups. I have a joining table called storesingroups for this reason. Stores and Users have a RetailerId as a foreign key. There is other tables that are linked in the EF model such as user details and logs etc for each store.

What i want to do is return all groups that is linked to a certain username but only return the group details and any stores in that group, any other tables that are linked to the store entity i dont need.

I have messed around with a number of different queries to try and do this the closest being below, however i am sure there is a better way. The code was also causing an out of memory exception so i know something isnt right somewhere

```
 var results1 = (from g in db.Groups
                        from gs in db.StoresInGroups
                         from s in db.Stores
                     //    from r in db.Retailers
                       from u in db.UserProfileEFs
                       where s.RetailerRetailerId == u.RetailerId
                       where g.GroupId == gs.GroupId
                       where gs.StoreId == s.StoreId
                        where u.UserName == this.User.Identity.Name
                        where g.GroupId == u.GroupId
                        select new { Groups = g}).ToList();
```

**EDIT:**

ok so managed to get the results i need via this query:

```
var results2 = (from g in db.Groups
                           join u in db.UserProfileEFs on g equals u.Group where u.UserName == this.User.Identity.Name

                           select new { Group = g });
```

what i now need to do is change the projection as it is currently returning userprofiles as well as stores in group, how do i get the query to not return userprofiles?

Comment: If you are using lazy loading, it isn't returning that data unless you interrogate it.

Comment: I think, that cross join is not the best solution for this case...

Comment: Lazy loading is disabled, this is being used in a Web Api and so after this is being serialized to JSON. Interestingly when you look at the query EF creates it actually creates inner joins for the code above!

Comment: To do left outer joins, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/vstudio/bb397895.aspx